# Calling C function from JavaScript using emscripten

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly, emscripten

I am currently trying to compile C to wasm and use it on a website. But I have had zero luck so far.

What I currently have is the following C source file:

```c
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int sum(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

I compile it using the following emscripten command:

```bash
emcc test.c -o test.js -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_sum']" -sMODULARIZE
```

This produces `test.wasm` and `test.js`.

Then, I have the following html code:

```html
<html>
<!--...-->
<body>
  <script type="module">
    var _import = import('test.js');
    _import.then((instance) => {
      console.log(instance._sum());
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I start up a development server, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: instance._sum is not a function
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8000/:7
    promise callback* http://localhost:8000/:6
```

I also tried `instance.sum` and `instance.ccall('sum')`, both with the same result.

I have no clue at this point what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show us what is logged if you run `console.log(instance)`?

Comment: @asdf3.14159 Yes, it logs `Object { … }`, and when I expand it, it shows `Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"`